# Tweepy Streamer Limiting Tweets to 140 Characters

Tags: twitter, streaming, tweepy

I created a tweepy listener to collect tweets into a local MongoDB during the first presidential debate but have realized that the tweets I have been collecting are limited to 140 characters and many are being cut off at the 140 character limit.  In my stream I had definied `tweet_mode='extended'` which I thought would have resolved this issue, however, I am still not able to retrieve the full length of tweets longer than 140 characters.  Below is my code:

```
auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN, twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

# Create a listener MyListener that streams and stores tweets to a local MongoDB

class MyListener(StreamListener):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.list_of_tweets = deque([], maxlen=5)
        
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            tweet_text = json.loads(data)
            self.list_of_tweets.append(tweet_text)
            self.print_list_of_tweets()
            db['09292020'].insert_one(tweet_text)
        except:
            None
          
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

    def print_list_of_tweets(self):
        display.clear_output(wait=True)
        for index, tweet_text in enumerate(self.list_of_tweets):
            m='{}. {}\n\n'.format(index, tweet_text)
            print(m)  

debate_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener(), tweet_mode='extended')
debate_stream = debate_stream.filter(track=['insert', 'debate', 'keywords', 'here'])
```

Any input into how I can obtain the full extended tweet via this listener would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tweet_mode=extended` has no effect on the legacy standard streaming API, as Tweets are delivered in both truncated (140) and extended (280) form by default.

So you'll want your Stream Listener set up like this:

`debate_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())`

What you should be seeing is that the JSON object for longer Tweets has a `text` field of 140 characters, but contains an additional dictionary called `extended_tweet` which in turn contains a `full_text` field with the full Tweet text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your second to last line to

```
debate_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener()).extended_tweet["full_text"]
```

Not sure, if this will work, but try it out.

Comment: I am receiving the following error when switching to the above code:  `AttributeError: 'Stream' object has no attribute 'extended_tweet'`